# excel files edited from all devices

Tags: asp.net, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wanna get your opinoun for my situation.My customer has  excel files which is edited daily by herself.My customer wanna reach and edit from  all devices like tablet pc,laptop pc or mobile phone  inside her company .(it is local network)
One solution I can find is install a excel server using the share point.in that way I am planing to reach her excel file via browser from all devices and edited.
but I am not famillier with the share point.and no idea how make an excel page available on the local network.
My question is what should be the best solition on this issue.is the using share point is only solution.?whats your opinoun on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If Internet is also available on all devices, you can go for a ready made solution of Google Drive, It will sync automatically.. But the Company IT policy could be a Constraint